# CEF load HTML from embedded resource

Tags: c++, windows, resources, chromium-embedded

I want to load HTML from a resource embedded in my exe file. I am using C++ and CEF3 on Windows 8.1.

I've seen [this article](https://thechriskent.com/2014/05/12/use-embedded-resources-in-cefsharp/) and it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for but it concerns CefSharp.

Is there a way to do that with C++?

Also, can I embed a folder containing HTML and CSS files and load it with CEF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any file to the resources. Open the project's *.rc file with notepad. Add the following line to *.rc file:

```
123 RCDATA "c:\\source-path\\source-file.htm"
```

You can use any predefined value, example `#define ID_STRING 1234`

Open the resource during run time, then copy to disk or open the data directly. This code will try to save the file to disk, then open file disk.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>

void foo()
{
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(123), RT_RCDATA);
    if(!hrsrc)
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, L"resource `123 RCDATA` not found", 0, 0);
        return;
    }

    HMODULE hmodule = 0;
    HGLOBAL hglobal = LoadResource(hmodule, hrsrc);

    void *data = LockResource(hglobal);
    DWORD size = SizeofResource(hmodule, hrsrc);

    const wchar_t* filename = L"c:\\temp\\testout.htm";
    std::ofstream fout(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if(!fout)
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, L"Cannot make temp file", 0, 0);
        return;     
    }
    fout.write((char*)data, size);
    fout.close();

    ShellExecuteW(0, NULL, filename, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
}
```

`RCDATA` is constant `10`

`RT_RCDATA` is a macro for `MAKEINTRESOURCE(10)`

Comment: That's perfect!! Thank you very much!!